# perl Net::Telnet wait_for a middle character, while the "print" action still buffering data

Tags: perl, command, buffer, telnet

I'm using perl with the [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTelnet) module.

My problem is while sending a command that has an output of 1000 rows, the "wait_for" looks for a string in the middle.

The `wait_for` stops but the buffer is still keeps storing the command's output.

the problem is with the next command that I send - I'm getting the rest of the first command's output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Telnet;

$session = new ... ();
$session->print("cmd 1");
my $output = $session->wait_for(String => "AAA");

$session->buffer_empty;
$session->print("cmd 2");
my $output2 = $session->wait_for(String => "#");
```

I've tried sending a "$session->buffer_empty" but it doesn't help.  Does anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: I grabbed the rest of the data with $session->getlines(Timeout => 1);

Answer (score 1):

The problem here might be that `cmd 1` is still filling the input buffer even after `buffer_empty` is called. If you know what is at the very end of output of `cmd 1`, the best solution would be to add another `waitfor` to make sure 'cmd 1' has finished running before issuing 'cmd 2'.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Telnet;

$session = new ... ();
$session->print("cmd 1");
my $output = $session->wait_for(String => "AAA");

$session->wait_for(Match => '/>$/');
$session->buffer_empty;

$session->print("cmd 2");
my $output2 = $session->wait_for(String => "#");
```

Another option would be to add `sleep` before calling `buffer_empty`.

Comment: You're right, i didn't though of that. but the command is an argument, and not all the commands have to wait twice. so this solution might stuck the script. with ->getlines(<timeout>) - it doesn't metter if i have another data or not. it simply wait for X seconds and then keep going ....